# Verificar se o login existe em jQuery antes de enviar o formulário

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso desenvolver um sistema no qual ao preencher o cadastro do cliente, seja verificado se o e-mail cadastrado já existe no banco de dados, e se já existir, que informe ao usuário (via Ajax) que ele já possui este e-mail cadastrado, e, caso contrário, que faça o envio normal.

Mas não quero ter que clicar em Enviar primeiro, pra depois saber se existe ou não... Há alguma forma de elaborar isto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma interessante de fazer isso é ao preencher o campo `e-mail` você usar a o método `change` do jQuery para enviar um Ajax.

No PHP ele fará um `select` verificando se esse e-mail existe na base, e se existir, você poderá mostrar uma mensagem de que o e-mail já existe no `success` do Ajax.

Exemplo:

```js
var email = $("#email");
email.change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'teste.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: email.val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.email) { // se existir
        $("#resposta").append('Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email');
      }

    },
    error: function() {
      $("#resultado").show().fadeOut(5000);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='email'>
<div id='resposta'></div>
```

No php faça um teste apenas retornando verdadeiro para ver se o retorno do ajax esta funcionando, depois disso você pode fazer o `select` e colocar o retorno adequado:

```
   $output = true;
   echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Acho que isto seria o suficiente, você teria um exemplo prático disto? Ou pelomenos uma solução parecida? Grato!

Comment: Uso o CodeIgniter

Comment: Não deu certo... Aponta erro no jQuery

Comment: @AndréBaill no php você precisa apenas fazer um select e retonar se existe um email acredito que não seja dificil modificar o codigo para realizar isto no codeigniter, quanto ao erro no jquery qual seria ele ?

Comment: @gustavox será que você tem idéia do que pode estar ocorrendo? não consegui mesmo elaborar.

Comment: ele não retorna nada... Por mais que eu faça a pesquisa apenas na variavel, sem entrar no mysql... não retorna...

Comment: Será que você conseguiria elaborar um outro exemplo? Neste não consegui.. A partir do PHP eu consigo elaborar as questões de mySQL, só não entendo nada de jquery.. @gabrielrodrigues

Comment: Lamento @AndréBaill, só editei pra corrigir algumas pequenas imprecisões do texto... mas olha só, ele não retorna nenhum erro? Este tipo de situação é complicada de ajudar, porque por depender de arquivo externo (PHP e Json) fica difícil de criar um exemplo verificável (pra quem for tentar ajudar poder ir testando)... mas só pra constar, vc disse que ele não retorna nada, mas a página para de rodar? Porque se ficar em loop infinito, pode ser erro no PHP.

Comment: Sim, normal... Mas o resultado não vem, e entrei no console e aponta erro de jQuery.

Comment: @AndréBaill editei a resposta deixando mais simples, faça um teste, aqui esta funcionando.

Comment: Repostei a questão de forma diferente: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76686/verificar-se-o-email-preenchido-j%C3%A1-existe-no-banco-de-dados-sem-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Sei que faz tempo esse POST, mas aqui vai uma coisa que talvez ajude vocês, você poderia simular o envio do formulário com uma div ou button estizada como botão submit, segue a ideia abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#bs-em .button').on('click', function(){
    var email = $('#email').val();


    //Envia o valor de email através do método POST para a página verify 
//para verificar se o email já existe, caso exista ele retorna falso 
//através do parâmetro 'e' da função, se não existe ele retorna true, 
//aí é só comparar esses valores, e caso seja true, você usa o método submit()
 //para poder submeter o formulário a página insert.php. Você também pode usar $.ajax.


    $.post('configs/verify.php', {email: email}, function(e){
      //Então você faz uma comparação de valores, entre false e true
      if(e == false){
        alert("Desculpe, o email informado já existe.");
      }else{
        $('#bs-em').submit();
      }
    });
  });
});

//O código JQuery está um pouco genérico, pq estou fazendo diretamente 
//pelo pt.stackoverflow, então não pude testar o código ainda, caso der algum erro, 
//me avisa, provavelmente pode dar em duas coisas, ou na forma que fiz a comparação 
//do parâmetro 'e', ou então o if dentro da função $.post, por isso eu queria testar, 
//mas qualquer coisa me avisem, a ideia é mais ou menos essa, verificar se existe 
//antes de submeter o formulário
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  background-color: #333;
}
form{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  padding: 8px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0;
}
form input[type=text]{
  border: 0;
  width: 284px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 7px;
}
form .button{
  width: 130px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #45349d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 7px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="insert.php" method="post" id="bs-em">
  <input type="text" name="email" class="email" id="email" placeholder="Inserir E-mail aqui" />
  <div class="button">ENVIAR</div>
</form>
```

Espero ter ajudado Pessoal! Valeu