# Verificar se o email preenchido já existe no banco de dados sem refresh

Tags: php, jquery

Preciso que ao preencher um email no campo email, busque no banco de dados e retorne uma mensagem avisando se já estiver este e-mail cadastrado no banco de dados. Elaboramos o jQuery + PHP conforme respostas postadas numa questão que enviamos, mas de igual forma, não consegui elaborar.

## verificaEmail.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='email'>
<div id='resposta'></div>

<script language="javascript">
    var email = $("#email");
        email.change(function() {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'verificaEmail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: email.val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              if (data.email) { // se existir
                $("#resposta").append('Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email');
              }

            },
            error: function() {
              $("#resultado").show().fadeOut(5000);
            }
          });
        });
</script>
```

## verificaEmail.php

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['email']) ) {
    $vEmail = $_POST['email'];
    if ( $vEmail == "joao@xserver.com" ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

O caso é, que ao executar, não retorna nada... Nem no console retorna erros... Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: quando vc acessa `verificaEmail.php` direto aparece algo?, de um print_r em $_POST?

Comment: Não chegou a executar o arquivo PHP, creio eu... porque dei um print_r no post e não retornou nada... nem o array(), também tentei echo "teste"; e não retornou nada também.

Comment: Coloca em lá no data:"email=" + email.val()

Comment: De um checada nesses itens, Para cada letra digitada vc manda um ajax(onchange)? `data: email.val(),` passa o nome do campo enviado acredito que seja assim: `data:{"email" : email.val()},`

Comment: Não deu certo.. Mas creio eu que não está nem acessando o arquivo PHP, porque não retorna nada..

Comment: Fiz da seguinte forma: $output = $_POST['email'];
echo json_encode($output); e observei no console, passou o email digitado, porém, se eu retornar TRUE, ele teoricamente deveria me dizer que o email existe.. E não o faz...

Comment: Lembre de fazer o `$.parseJSON()` em data no js.

Comment: Não sei como faz.

Comment: Mas o problema já está sendo no PHP, porque eu até consegui um retorno... mas não dá pra usar isto para fazer a verificação

Comment: Se eu colocar: echo json_encode($_POST['email']);, ele retorna o email preenchido. Gostaria de fazer a verificação, como é feito? Pode ser um if simples.. sem o banco de dados, depois eu ajusto o db.

Comment: A verificação já esta sendo feita no php, é so mandar a msg pro js.
`data = $.parseJSON(data);  $("#resposta").append(data.email)`. troque `data.email` pelo nome q vc deu no json_enconde()

Comment: Não entendi. Onde eu coloco data = $.parseJSON(data); ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26247/discussion-between-rray-and-andre-baill).

Comment: Deu certo. Agora só trato o PHP com busca no banco de dados. Agradeço muito sua ajuda @rray

Comment: Ok funcionou, porém, se eu digitar o email que está lá aparece a mensagem... Mas se eu digitar um outro email, a mensagem continua, e não faz uma nova verificação de existência.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eis a solução com a ajuda do @rray.

## verificaEmail.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='email'>
<div id='resposta'></div>

<script language="javascript">
    var email = $("#email"); 
        email.blur(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'verificaEmail.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{"email" : email.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.email);
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

## verificaEmail.php

```
<?php
#Verifica se tem um email para pesquisa
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ 

    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailPostado = $_POST['email'];

    #Conecta banco de dados 
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "outrasintencoes");
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email')); 
    else 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Usuário valido.' )); 
}
?>
```