# Formulário de cadastro e planos HTML sem banco de dados

Tags: php, html, tabela-banco-de-dados

Baixei um formulário de cadastro e planos passo a passo e com o html já pronto e grátis, porém não grava no banco de dados.

O que precisa para gravar no banco de dados?

Código:

```html
</head>
 <body ng-controller="formPassosCtrl">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-centered">
    <div id="cadastroTopTop" class="cadastro fade-in">
     <div class="box-cadastro" ng-hide="passo == 5">
            <div class="passos">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="circ-passos">
                    <div ng-class="{active_passo: passo == 1}" class="circ-passos-item fade-in">
                        <span>1</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Escolha o<br>plano desejado</p>
                </div>
                <div class="circ-passos">
                    <div ng-class="{active_passo: passo == 2}" class="circ-passos-item fade-in">
                        <span>2</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Dados da<br>conta</p>
                </div>
                <div class="circ-passos">
                    <div ng-class="{active_passo: passo == 3}" class="circ-passos-item fade-in">
                        <span>3</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Dados<br>pessoais</p>
                </div>
                <div class="circ-passos">
                    <div ng-class="{active_passo: passo == 4}" class="circ-passos-item fade-in">
                        <span>4</span>
                    </div>
                    <p>Dados da<br>loja virtual</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-passos">
                <div ng-show="passo == 1" class="passo passo-1 fade-in">
                    <form role="form" name="cadastro_1" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="fnt-12 fade-in" ng-show="ir && !cadastro.plano"><strong>ERRO: É obrigatório escolher um plano</strong></span>
                            <span class="fnt-12 fade-in" ng-hide="ir && !cadastro.plano || cadastro.plano">Escolha um plano abaixo</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                                <div class="planos planos-cadastro one" id="plano-mensal" ng-click="marcaPlano('plano-mensal');">
                                    <div class="header-plano">
                                        <h2>Plano<br>Mensal</h2>
                                        <p>Menor preço<br>do mercado</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="preco-plano">
                                        <span>R$</span>
                                        <strong>60,00</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                                <div class="planos planos-cadastro two" id="plano-trimestral" ng-click="marcaPlano('plano-trimestral');">
                                    <div class="header-plano">
                                        <h2>Plano Trimestral</h2>
                                                        <p><strong>10%</strong> de desconto</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="preco-plano">
                                                        <span>R$</span>
                                                        <strong>162,00</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                                <div class="planos planos-cadastro three" id="plano-semestral" ng-click="marcaPlano('plano-semestral');">
                                    <div class="header-plano">
                                        <h2>Plano Semestral</h2>
                                                        <p><strong>15%</strong> de desconto</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="preco-plano">
                                                        <span>R$</span>
                                                        <strong>306,00</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                                <div class="planos planos-cadastro four"  id="plano-anual" ng-click="marcaPlano('plano-anual');">
                                    <div class="header-plano header-destaque">
            <span class="label label-warning plano-destaque">Mais Vendido</span>
                                        <h2>Plano<br>Anual</h2>
                                                    <p><strong>20%</strong> de desconto</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="preco-plano">
                                                <span>R$</span>
                                                <strong>576,00</strong>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center planos-30dias-desconto">
                                                <label class="fnt-17">Todos os planos com 30 dias grátis</label>
                                                <br>
                                                <a href="./planos">Conheça as caracteristicas de cada plano</a>
                                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="planoInput" ng-model="cadastro.plano" ng-required="!voltar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls-passos text-right">
                            <button id="btnPassoOne" ng-click="passosCadastro(true, cadastro, 'cadastro_1');voltar=false;ir=true" class="fade-in btn btn-primary">Pr&oacute;ximo <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="passo == 2" class="passo passo-2 fade-in">
                    <form role="form" name="cadastro_2" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group emailCampo">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.email" placeholder="Informe um e-mail válido!" ng-required="!voltar">
                            
                            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true" ng-mouseover="colocarCorTooltip()" ng-show="emailInvalido" ng-hide="!emailInvalido" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Deve conter @ e .com"></i>
                            
                            <div class="fnt-10 text-left emailja fade-in" ng-show="emailja" ng-hide="!emailja">E-mail j&aacute; cadastrado. Deseja <a href="#modal-login" data-toggle="modal" target="_self" data-target="#modal-login" class="green">acessar sua conta</a>?</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6 senha-cadastro">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" id="senha" ng-model="cadastro.senha" placeholder="Senha" ng-required="!voltar">
                                <ul ng-show="forca_senha" ng-class="{red: forca_senha <= 10, orange: forca_senha > 10, yellow: forca_senha > 30, green: forca_senha > 50}">
                                    <li><i ng-show="forca_senha > 1" class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                    <li><i ng-show="forca_senha > 10" class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                    <li><i ng-show="forca_senha > 30" class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                    <li><i ng-show="forca_senha > 50" class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirm_senha" id="confirm_senha" ng-model="cadastro.confirm_senha" placeholder="Confirme a senha" ng-required="!voltar" pw-check="senha">
                            </div>
                            <span ng-show="cadastro_2.confirm_senha.$error.pwmatch && cadastro.confirm_senha" class="aviso fade-in">senhas diferentes</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6 senha-cadastro text-left fade-in" ng-show="senhaFraca" ng-hide="!senhaFraca">
                                <div>
                                    <span class="fnt-10 fade-in">For&ccedil;a m&iacute;nima:</span>
                                    <ul class="orange fade-in">
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls-passos">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                                    <button ng-show="passo > 1" ng-click="passosCadastro(false, cadastro, 'cadastro_2');voltar=true" class="btn btn-primary fade-in"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Voltar</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                    <button ng-click="passosCadastro(true, cadastro, 'cadastro_2');voltar=false" class="fade-in btn btn-primary">Pr&oacute;ximo <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="passo == 3" class="passo passo-3 fade-in">
                    <form role="form" name="cadastro_3" novalidate>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.nome" placeholder="Seu nome" ng-required="!voltar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.cpf" placeholder="Seu CPF" ng-required="!voltar" mask="999.999.999-99" mask-restrict="reject">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dtNascimento" maxlength="10" placeholder="Sua data de nascimento" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" ng-model="cadastro.dtNascimento" mask="99/99/9999" ng-required="!voltar" mask-restrict="reject">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls-passos">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                                    <button ng-show="passo > 1" ng-click="passosCadastro(false, cadastro, 'cadastro_3');voltar=true" class="btn btn-primary fade-in"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Voltar</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                    <button ng-click="passosCadastro(true, cadastro, 'cadastro_3');voltar=false" class="fade-in btn btn-primary">Pr&oacute;ximo <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="passo == 4" class="passo passo-4 fade-in">
                    <form role="form" name="cadastro_4" novalidate>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ" mask="99.999.999/9999-99" mask-restrict="reject">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="!voltar" ng-model="cadastro.telefone" placeholder="Telefone" mask="(99) 9999-9999?9" mask-restrict='reject'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group emailCampo">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">www.</span>
                                <input id="siteUrl" type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" ng-model="cadastro.dominioDesejado" ng-required="!voltar" placeholder="Qual dom&iacute;nio deseja utilizar?">
                                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true" ng-mouseover="colocarCorTooltip()" ng-show="siteInvalido" ng-hide="!siteInvalido" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Deve conter .com, .br ou semelhantes"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6 cepCampo">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-required="!voltar" ng-model="cadastro.cep" placeholder="CEP" mask="99.999-999" mask-restrict='reject' ng-blur="buscaCep(cadastro.cep)">
                                <i class="fa {{loadingCepImage}}" ng-show="loadingCep"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.estado" ng-options="estado.uf as estado.nome for estado in estados" ng-required="!voltar" ng-change="cidade(cadastro.estado)">
                                    <option value="" disabled selected>Estado</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.endereco" placeholder="Endere&ccedil;o" ng-required="!voltar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.numero" placeholder="N&uacute;mero" ng-required="!voltar" mask="9999999999999999999999999999" mask-restrict='reject' mask-validate='false'>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.complemento" placeholder="Complemento">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.bairro" placeholder="Bairro" ng-required="!voltar">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.cidade" placeholder="Cidade">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cadastro.codPromocional" placeholder="C&oacute;digo Promocional?">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label ng-required="!cadastro.termos"><input type="checkbox" ng-required="!voltar" ng-model="cadastro.termos" value="aceito">Aceito os <a href="termo.html" class="green">termos de uso</a></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="controls-passos">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
                                    <button ng-show="passo > 1" ng-click="passosCadastro(false, cadastro, 'cadastro_4');voltar=true" class="btn btn-primary fade-in"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Voltar</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                                    <button ng-click="passosCadastro(true, cadastro, 'cadastro_4');voltar=false" class="fade-in btn btn-primary">Pr&oacute;ximo <i class="fa {{loadingSend}}" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es seguras! Fique tranquilo :)"></i>
        </div>
        <!-- Mensagem de cadastrado com  sucesso -->
                 <div ng-show="passo == 5" class="row padding-cadastro cadastro wow pulse" data-wow-duration="1500ms" data-wow-iteration="2">
                     <div class="col-lg-12">
                         <div class="box-cadastro fade-in">
                             <div class="passo passo-5 fade-in finalAgradecimento">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check fade-in one" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <p class="fade-in two">Sua loja virtual foi criada</p>
         <p class="fade-in three fnt-17"><strong>Foi lhe enviado um e-mail com as informações necessárias</strong></p>
         
<script>         
<input type='text' id='email'>
<div id='resposta'></div>

<script language="javascript">
    var email = $("#email"); 
        email.blur(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'js/json/verifica_email.php', 
                type: 'POST', 
                data:{"email" : email.val()}, 
                success: function(data) { 
                console.log(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data); 
                $("#resposta").text(data.email);
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
    </script>
                                </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                </div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

verifica_email.php

```html
<?php
#Verifica se tem um email para pesquisa
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ 

    #Recebe o Email Postado
    $emailPostado = $_POST['email'];

    #Conecta banco de dados 
 $myHost = "localhost"; // use seu nome de host
    $myUserName = "usuário";   // nome de usuário
    $myPassword = "senha";   // sua senha de login
    $myDataBaseName = "banco de dados"; // nome do banco de dados

    $con = mysqli_connect( "", "", "", "" );

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '{}'") or print mysql_error();

    #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email')); 
    else 
        echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Parabéns! Você poderá usar este e-mail como usuário.' )); 
}
?>
```

Estrutura da tabela

```html
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `pagamento_aluguel`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura da tabela `clientes`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `clientes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `plano-mensal` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `plano-trimestral` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `plano-semestral` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `plano-anual` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `email` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `password` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `nome` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `nascimento` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `dominio` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `cep` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `complemento` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Oi amigo, tenho verifica_email.php já postei @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Não tenho, tenho que criar um @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Ok amigo vou fazer agora, vou tentar criar o banco de dados assim que estiver pronto eu aviso @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Pronto amigo fiz a tabela já está no post, não sei se está 100% fiz conforme que tem no cadastro @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: O código para criar a tabela funciona, porém os códigos das paginas não estão a ponto de funcionar. Tá muito zoado.

Comment: Amigo veja a fonte https://github.com/MuriloEduardo/formulario-passo-a-passo-design-clin @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Bom dia amigo, na verdade eu peguei esses códigos do arquivo verifica_email.php aqui no fórum veja se o amigo consegue corrigir os erros e depois postar aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76686/verificar-se-o-email-preenchido-j%C3%A1-existe-no-banco-de-dados-sem-refresh @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Amigo parabéns ficou show, agora vou tentar inserir no meu admin, se eu não consegui vou pedir ajuda com o amigo, Obrigado, Não sei agradecer o amigo @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Bom dia, achei um site que usa esta tabela está funcionando 100% Mandei um email com o link do site quem sabe o amigo consegue fazer funcionar esta tabela @LeoCaracciolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> O script do  [github](https://anotepad.com/notes/kibee6) apontado no seu comentário não funciona, pois misturar o jQuery com o AngularJS dessa maneira é estar pedindo por problemas.

A solução passa por `"desmisturar"` o codigo utilizando apenas `jQuery`.

**pagina HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html class="">

    <head>

        <title>Cadastro</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">

         <!-- Ícones -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>

        <style>
        .erro{
            border-color: red;
        }
        FONT .obrigatorio {
            color:red;
        }

        .centered {
            margin: 30px auto;
            width: 50%; /* Valor da Largura */
        }

        .btn-primary {
            background: #0099cc;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .btn-success{
            background: #198A4E;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        </style>

        <script src="funcoes.js"></script>

    </head>

<body>
<div class="centered"><div class="container"><div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-centered">
    <div class="box-cadastro">
        <div class="passos">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="circ-passos">
                <div class="active_passo circ-passos-item fade-in">
                    <span>1</span>
                </div>
                <p>Escolha o<br>plano desejado</p>
            </div>
            <div class="circ-passos" activeTooltip="planos" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" >
                <div class="circ-passos-item fade-in">
                    <span>2</span>
                </div>
                <p>Dados da<br>conta</p>
            </div>
            <div class="circ-passos">
                <div class="circ-passos-item fade-in">
                    <span>3</span>
                </div>
                <p>Dados<br>pessoais</p>
            </div>
            <div class="circ-passos">
                <div class="circ-passos-item fade-in">
                    <span>4</span>
                </div>
                <p>Dados da<br>loja virtual</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form id="form_cadastro">
            <div class="form-passos">
                <div id="passo-1" class="passo passo-1 fade-in">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <span class="fnt-12 fade-in">Clique no plano escolhido para marca-lo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <div class="planos planos-cadastro one" id="11">
                                <div class="header-plano">
                                    <h2>Plano<br>Mensal</h2>
                                    <p>Menor pre&ccedil;o do mercado</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="preco-plano">
                                    <span>R$</span>
                                    <strong>35,00</strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <div class="planos planos-cadastro two" id="12">
                                <div class="header-plano">
                                    <h2>Plano Trimestral</h2>
                                    <p><strong>14%</strong> de desconto</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="preco-plano">
                                    <span>R$</span>
                                    <strong>90,00</strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <div class="planos planos-cadastro three" id="13">
                                <div class="header-plano">
                                    <h2>Plano Semestral</h2>
                                    <p><strong>28%</strong> de desconto</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="preco-plano">
                                    <span>R$</span>
                                    <strong>150,00</strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
                            <div class="planos planos-cadastro four" id="14">
                                <div class="header-plano">
                                    <span class="label label-warning plano-destaque">Mais Vendido</span>
                                    <h2>Plano<br>Anual</h2>
                                    <p><strong>42%</strong> de desconto</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="preco-plano">
                                    <span>R$</span>
                                    <strong>240,00</strong>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 text-center planos-30dias-desconto">
                            <label class="fnt-17">Todos os planos com 30 dias gr&aacute;tis</label>
                            <br>
                            <a href="#myModalPlanos" class="btn btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal">Conhe&ccedil;a as caracteristicas de cada plano</a>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="planoInput" name="fieldCod_Plano">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="passo-2" class="passo passo-2 fade-in" style="display:none">
                    <div class="form-group emailCampo">
                        <input type="email" id="emailPrimary" autocomplete='email' class="form-control email obrigatorio" name="fieldEmail" placeholder="Informe um e-mail válido!" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div id="emailja" style="display:none" class="fnt-12 text-left emailja fade-in">E-mail j&aacute; cadastrado. Deseja <a href="#modal-login" data-toggle="modal" target="_self" data-target="#modal-login" class="green">acessar sua conta</a>?
                            </div>
                            <div id="emailerro" style="display:none" class="fnt-12 text-left emailja fade-in">E-mail inválidado. Caso exista <a href="#modal-contato" data-toggle="modal" target="_self" data-target="#modal-contato" class="green">entre em contato conosco</a>!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control senha obrigatorio" autocomplete="off" name="fieldSenha" id="senha" placeholder="Senha">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4 fnt-12 text-center">
                                <div id="senhaBarra" class="progress" style="display: none;">
                                   <div id="senhaForca" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">
                                   </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-4">
                             <input type="password" class="form-control senha obrigatorio" autocomplete="off" name="fieldSenha2" id="confirm_senha" placeholder="Confirme a senha">
                            </div>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div id="passo-3" class="passo passo-3 fade-in" style="display:none">
                    <div class="form-group emailCampo">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control obrigatorio" autocomplete='name' name="fieldResponsavel" id="nome" placeholder="Seu nome" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group emailCampo">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control obrigatorio cpf" name="fieldCpf" id="cpf"  placeholder="Seu CPF">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control obrigatorio data" id="dtNascimento" name="fieldDt_Nascimento" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" placeholder="Data nascimento">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> (dd/mm/aaaa)</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="passo-4" class="passo passo-4 fade-in" style="display:none">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control obrigatorio" name="fieldLoja" placeholder="T&iacute;tulo da loja virtual" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control cnpj" name="fieldCnpj" id="cnpj" placeholder="CNPJ (opcional)" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control telefone obrigatorio" autocomplete="tel" name="fieldFone" placeholder="Telefone">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group emailCampo">
                            <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">http://www.</span>
                            <input id="siteUrl" type="text" class="form-control obrigatorio" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" name="fieldUrl_Interna" placeholder="Qual dom&iacute;nio deseja utilizar?">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control obrigatorio" name="fieldRamo" id="ramo" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Escolha o ramo da sua loja virtual">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6 cepCampo">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control cep obrigatorio" name="fieldCep" autocomplete="postal-code" id="cep" placeholder="CEP" maxlength="10">
    <i class="fa {{loadingCepImage}}"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" id="estado" class="form-control obrigatorio" name="fieldEstado" placeholder="Estado">                                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="endereco" class="form-control obrigatorio" name="fieldRua" autocomplete="address-line1" placeholder="Rua/Avenida">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" id="numero" class="form-control numero obrigatorio" name="fieldNumero" placeholder="N&uacute;mero">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fieldComplemento" placeholder="Complemento (opcional)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" id="bairro" class="form-control obrigatorio" name="fieldBairro" placeholder="Bairro">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <input type="text" id="cidade" class="form-control obrigatorio" name="fieldCidade" placeholder="Cidade">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="codPromocionalAddon">
                                <i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codPromocional" placeholder="C&oacute;digo Promocional?" aria-describedby="codPromocionalAddon">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" name="termos" id="termos">Aceito os <a href="termo.html" target="_blank" class="green">termos de uso</a></label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row vertical-align">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6 text-left">
                                <span>
                                C&oacute;digo de seguran&ccedil;a
                                <span id="chaveKey" style="border-radius: 3px;" class="fade-in"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control numero obrigatorio" placeholder="Repita o c&oacute;digo ao lado" name="codSeguranca" id="key">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-right" id="msg_erro" style="display:none; font-weight:bold; color:red;"></div>

                    <div class="row controls-passos">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right pull-right">
                            <button type="button" class="continuar fade-in btn btn btn-success pull-right">Continuar <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left pull-left">
                        <button type="button" class="voltar btn btn-link fade-in"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Voltar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Todas as informa&ccedil;&otilde;es s&atilde;o criptografadas!"></i>
    </div>
</div>

</div></div></div>

    <!-- Modal HTML SUCESSO-->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Resultado da requisição </h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <p>Cadastro realizado com sucesso</p>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal HTML ERRO-->
    <div id="myModalErro" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Resultado da requisição.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                     <div id="resultado"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


   <!-- Modal HTML CARACTERISTICAS PLANOS -->
   <div id="myModalPlanos" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">Caracteristicas dos planos </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <p>Os planos são .........</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div id="modal-login" class="modal fade">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <h4 class="modal-title">Login </h4>
               </div>
               <form id="mudarsenha" method="post" name="form_mudar_senha" action="" autocomplete="off">
               <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="md-form ml-0 mr-0">
                        <input name="senha" type="password">
                    </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light" ><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></span> Enviar</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
               </form>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>


     <!-- Modal erro cep -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModalCep" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
           <h4 class="modal-title">CEP </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
           <p><span id="resultCep"></span></p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Arquivo CSS - normalize.css --> [Anotepad.com](https://anotepad.com/notes/kibee6)

Arquivo JS - funcoes.js --> [Anotepad.com](https://anotepad.com/notes/bckng9)

**key.php**

```
<?php

$numero = rand() % 9000 + 1000;

echo $numero;

?>
```

**verifica_url.php**

```
 <?php

 $url=$_POST['url'];

    if (!checkdnsrr($url)){
        echo 2;
    }
?>
```

**verifica_email.php**

```
<?php

    $email=$_POST['email'];

    $validarDominio = function($dominio)
    {
          if( strstr( $dominio, '@' ) )
            list( $user, $dominio) = explode( '@', $dominio);

          return ( checkdnsrr( $dominio ) )
                ? 1 : 2;
    };

    if ($validarDominio($email)==2){
        echo 2;
    }else{

    //verifica se já existe esse email no banco

        //**********conexão*********    

        #Conecta banco de dados 
        $myHost = "localhost"; // use seu nome de host
        $myUserName = "USUARIO";   // nome de usuário
        $myPassword = "SENHA";   // sua senha de login
        $myDataBaseName = "Nome_DB"; // nome do banco de dados

            $con = mysqli_connect( $myHost, $myUserName, $myPassword, $myDataBaseName );  
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
              {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
              }

        //********** consulta para verificar se email já existe *********

        $sql="SELECT fieldEmail FROM clientela WHERE fieldEmail = '$email'";

        if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
          {
          // Return the number of rows in result set
          $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
          printf($rowcount);

          }

        mysqli_close($con);

    }
?>
```

**nova_loja.php**

```
 <?php

  $fieldCod_Plano=$_POST['fieldCod_Plano'];
  $fieldEmail=$_POST['fieldEmail'];
  $fieldSenha=md5($_POST['fieldSenha']);
  $fieldResponsavel=$_POST['fieldResponsavel'];
  $fieldCpf=$_POST['fieldCpf'];
  $fieldDt_Nascimento=$_POST['fieldDt_Nascimento'];
  $fieldCnpj=$_POST['fieldCnpj'];
  $fieldFone=$_POST['fieldFone'];
  $fieldUrl_Interna=$_POST['fieldUrl_Interna'];
  $fieldCep=$_POST['fieldCep'];
  $fieldRua=$_POST['fieldRua'];
  $fieldNumero=$_POST['fieldNumero'];
  $fieldComplemento=$_POST['fieldComplemento'];
  $fieldBairro=$_POST['fieldBairro'];
  $fieldCidade=$_POST['fieldCidade'];
  $fieldEstado=$_POST['fieldEstado'];
  $codPromocional=$_POST['codPromocional'];
  $termos=$_POST['termos'];


    //**********conexão*********    

        #Conecta banco de dados 
        $myHost = "localhost"; // use seu nome de host
        $myUserName = "USUARIO";   // nome de usuário
        $myPassword = "SENHA";   // sua senha de login
        $myDataBaseName = "Nome_DB"; // nome do banco de dados

        $con = mysqli_connect( $myHost, $myUserName, $myPassword, $myDataBaseName );  


    /********** consulta para verificar se email já existe.
      Embora isso já tenha sido verificado no passo 2,
      vai que até o usuário enviar o formulário no passo 4
      outro usuário cadastrou esse email. 
      Você pode evitar esse tipo de coisas criando
      uma coluna no banco com o valor default 0 (desativado).
      Ao fazer o INSERT mande um email com um token
      que ao ser clicado faz UPDATE na coluna para valor 1 (ativado)
     **************************************************************/

        $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT fieldEmail FROM clientela WHERE fieldEmail = '$fieldEmail'");

        #Se o retorno for maior do que zero, diz que já existe um.
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){

            $aviso = $fieldEmail;

        } else {
            /************************** insere dados no banco *********************************/

            $mysql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO clientela (fieldCod_Plano,fieldEmail,fieldSenha,fieldResponsavel,fieldCpf,fieldDt_Nascimento,fieldCnpj,fieldFone,fieldUrl_Interna,fieldCep,fieldRua,fieldNumero,fieldComplemento,fieldBairro,fieldCidade,fieldEstado,codPromocional,termos) VALUES ('$fieldCod_Plano','$fieldEmail','$fieldSenha','$fieldResponsavel','$fieldCpf','$fieldDt_Nascimento','$fieldCnpj','$fieldFone','$fieldUrl_Interna','$fieldCep','$fieldRua','$fieldNumero','$fieldComplemento','$fieldBairro','$fieldCidade','$fieldEstado','$codPromocional','$termos')");


            if($mysql){

                $aviso = 1;

            }
        }


        echo $aviso;

        mysqli_close($con); 

    ?>
```

**Tabela do banco**

> algumas colunas estão com comprimento 255, melhor seria adaptar esse comprimento para cada caso conforme seu entendimento a respeito.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `clientela`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clientela` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fieldCod_Plano` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `fieldEmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fieldSenha` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fieldResponsavel` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fieldCpf` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `fieldDt_Nascimento` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `fieldCnpj` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fieldFone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fieldUrl_Interna` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fieldCep` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `fieldRua` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fieldNumero` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `fieldComplemento` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fieldBairro` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fieldCidade` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fieldEstado` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `codPromocional` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `termos` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ativo` enum('1','0') DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Parabéns Leo ficou Show, só falta a tabela do banco, se o amigo tiver ai pronto manda para meu email ou postar aqui @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Boa tarde, arquivo não encontrado css, Source map error: request failed with status 404 Resource URL: /css/normalize.css Source Map URL: bootstrap.min.css.map @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: @Angelino No exemplo da resposta `normalize.css` está na mesma pasta não tem `/css/`

Comment: Fiz exatamente assim, mas continua o mesmo erro arquivo não encontrado @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">`

Comment: @Angelino Todos os arquivos estão na mesma pasta. Nada impede de colocar o css na pasta css mas tem que apontar o caminho corretamente

Comment: @Angelino, vc postou os códigos no seu servidor e está rodando ele ou está rodando o meu exemplo funcional?

Comment: Estou usando o Wampserve, o que mostra aqui é o mesmo que mostra no seu exemplo @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: @Angelino uso Chrome e não aparece nada, isso deve estar sendo no Firefox, mas não impede em nada do script rodar corretamente, deve ser algo relacionado a isso https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Source_map_errors esse normalize.css copiei do site e andei cortando alguma coisa que não interessava, deve haver algo mais que deveria ser cortado, mas não estou com essa paciencia toda

Comment: Verdade amigo, estou usando o Firefox pode ser este motivo mesmo

Comment: @Angelino provavelmente cortei algo no normalize.css que o ze lá tá reclamando

Comment: quando tiver tempo, vou verificar

Comment: amigo posso excluir a imagem que postei aqui?

Comment: sim pode sim amigo