# Verifica usuario Cadastrado

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

Estou usando esse tópico como exemplo de implementação.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76694

Ele funciona, me dá a mensagem que já existe um email cadastrado, MAS se eu clico em cadastrar ele cadastra mesmo assim, ignorando a mensagem.

Preciso de uma forma que obrigue o usuario a digitar novamente outro email

**verificaEmail.html**

```
<script language="javascript">
var email = $("#email"); 
    email.blur(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'verificaEmail.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data:{"email" : email.val()}, 
            success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data); 
            data = $.parseJSON(data); 
            $("#resposta").text(data.email);
        } 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

**verificaEmail.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])){ 

#Recebe o Email Postado
$emailPostado = $_POST['email'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "outrasintencoes");
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) 
    echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Ja existe um usuario cadastrado com este email')); 
else 
    echo json_encode(array('email' => 'Usuário valido.' )); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Dica! Facilita muito para responder, se colocar o link de referência apenas para situar sua pergunta, mas também é preciso colocar seu código para  sabermos onde está o erro

Answer (score 0):

Como eu faria:

PHP

```
#Recebe o Email Postado
$emailPostado = $_POST['email'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "outrasintencoes");
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '{$emailPostado}'") or print mysql_error();

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0) 
    echo json_encode(array('existe' => 'S', 'email' => 'email@email.com')); 
else 
    echo json_encode(array('existe' => 'N')); 
}
?>
```

JS

```
<script language="javascript">
var email = $("#email"); 
    email.blur(function() { 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'verificaEmail.php', 
            type: 'POST', 
            data:{"email" : email.val()}, 
            success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data); 
            data = $.parseJSON(data); 
            if(data.existe == 'S'){
             //Beleza dx ele fazer o cadastro
            }else{
             //Deixa o campo vermelho, disabilita o submit, avisa que email já está sendo usado
            }
        } 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Não sei se vai funcionar do jeito que tá, pode tá faltando uma vírgula ou coisa do tipo. pq n tive como debugar.